# Save part of Linq expression in Any and reuse

Tags: c#, linq

I have following Linq queries:

```
var leaders = _db.Context.Person.Where(p => p.PersonGroup.Any(pg => pg.IsActive && !pg.IsDeleted && pg.GroupType == 'leader'))

var staff = _db.Context.Person.Where(p => p.PersonGroup.Any(pg => pg.IsActive && !pg.IsDeleted && pg.GroupType == 'staff'))
```

How do I save
pg => pg.IsActive && !pg.IsDeleted part to a variable so my query can be simplified to something like

```
var staff = _db.Context.Person.Where(p => p.PersonGroup.Any(pg => pg.IsActiveAndNotDeleted && pg.GroupType == 'staff'))
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify why obvious approach of combining expressions did not work out...

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do will provide any benefit.  Just add the additional condition(s) you need to your lambda expression.

Comment: combining expressions works, but imagine "pg => pg.IsActive && !pg.IsDeleted" is very long and I don't want to repeat it over and over

Comment: `bool IsActiveAndNotDeleted(PersonGroup pg) => pg.IsActive && !pg.IsDeleted;`

Comment: And then `pg => IsActiveAndNotDeleted(pg);` in your lambda expression for `Any()`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it was my first though too, but then I wondered "would it translate?"

Comment: You can use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a sequence of `Persons`, where every `Person` has a property `PersonGroup`. Apparently PersonGroup is a sequence of zero or more similar items.

We don't know what these items are. What we do know, is that each of these items have Boolean properties `IsActive` and `IsDeleted` and a property `GroupType` which gives an indication of the type of the item: is it a `leader`, or a `staff`, or maybe something else.

Be aware: GroupType does not say anything about `PersonGroup`, but about one item in the PersonGroup. You didn't specify that all items in one PersonGroup have the same GroupType. As far as I know, it can be that PersonGroup has two items, one has GroupType `leader` and one has GroupType `staff`.

**Requirement:** Give me all Persons that have at least one item in property PersonGroup that is Active AND not IsDeleted AND has a third condition.

In your example, the third condition is `pg.GroupType == leader`, or `pg.GroupType == staff`. But it could be any condition on the type of items that are in PersonGroup.

I don't know the type of items that are in PersonGroup. Let's say they are items of class `Item`. Please replace this with the actual type of the items that are in PersonGroup.

My advice would be to create an *extension method* that takes as input an `IQueryable<Person>` and the third condition, and returns as output the query for all Persons that have at least one Item in property PersonGroup that is Active, not Deleted and that match the third condition.

If you are not familiar with extension methods, read [Extension methods demystified](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

```
public static IQueryable<Person> WhereAnyActiveGroup(
    this IQueryable<Person> persons,
    Expression<Func<Item,Boolean>> thirdCondition)
{
    return persons.Where(person => person.PersonGroup
        .Where(item => item.IsActive && !item.IsDeleted)
        .Where(thirdCondition)
        .Any());
}
```

TODO: invent a proper method name.

In words: from the input sequence of Persons, keep only those persons that have at least one Item in property PersonGroup that is Active and not Deleted and that matches the thirdCondition.

Usage:

```
using (var dbContext = new PersonelContext())
{
    var leaders = dbContext.Persons
        .WhereAnyActiveGroup(person => person.GroupType == 'leader'))
        .ToList();

    var staff = dbContext.Persons
        .WhereAnyActiveGroup(person => person.GroupType == 'staff'))
        .ToList();
}
```

You can even concatenate this with other LINQ methods:

```
var result = dbContext.Persons.Where(person => person.City == "New York")
   .WheraAnyActiveGroup(person => person.GroupType == 'staff')
   .GroupBy(person => person.Name)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest route would be some variation on providing a method that returns the result of a where:

```
private IEnumerable<Person> GetActiveInRole(string role){
  return _db.Context.Person.Where(p => p.PersonGroup.Any(pg => pg.IsActive && !pg.IsDeleted && pg.GroupType == role));
}
```

And then use that and build on it:

```
var staff = GetActiveInRole("staff");
var s = staff.Where(p => p.Name == "John");
```